# what is the proper way to clone Dynamics v9 on-premise environment?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-ce-onpremises

Helllo,

I have a working and up to date environment for Dynamics v9 on-prem.

I want to create another environment which will be identical to the above mentioned one.

Let's say that I want to clone PROD env and create a new Test environment with the same data and customizations that I have in prod.

What are the proper steps ? There is a lack of resources about this topic so I might have posted this in a wrong place. In this case, sorry and please refer me to the correct forum if you know such.

My idea is that, yes I would back up the sql server and then restore it but what happens on the Dynamics side ? Do I need to import any kind of configuration from the Dynamics Deployment Configuration ?

Or can I create the new environment and then restore the prod database in this env ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Backup the database of the existing D365 organization
2. Create a new D365 organization
3. Restore the new organization using the backup of step 1

The wizard will guide you through the process.

Comment: Do I perform 3rd step from the database(e.g. restore the backup mentioned in 1st step) or it's something that I have to trigger from Dynamics 365 deployment tool ?